# Como evitar que se corran decimales a la izquierda

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente problema soy algo nuevo trabajando con c# y MVC estoy realizando mantenimiento a un programa que esta en desarrollo, ese programa busca un producto en tiempo real  y al momento de guardarlo y mostrarlo en una hoja de pdf los decimales se están corriendo a la izquierda y agrega ,00

**Ejemplo**

**EN EL BUSCARDOR SALE: TELEFONO 1550,55**

**AL MOSTRARLO EN PDF SALE: 155055,00**

debuggeando encontre la parte que realiza este proceso

Solo mostrare el código que al cual hace referencia

En el Modelo tiene una clase que se llama **Item**

```
public class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            precio = 0;
    
        }

        public decimal precio;
    }
```

En el Controlador tiene una clase que se llama **Ordenes**

```
List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(collection["listaProductos"].Trim());
                foreach (Item i in items)
                {
                    int indexPrecio = i.nombre.IndexOf(" Precio: ");
                    if (indexPrecio != -1)
                    {
                        i.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(i.nombre.Split(new string[] {"Precio:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim());
                        i.nombre = i.nombre.Substring(0, indexPrecio);                        
                    }
                }
```

En esta linea estoy seguro que corre los decimales a la izquierda y me agrega los 2 decimales(,00)

```
i.precio = Convert.ToDecimal(i.nombre.Split(new string[] {"Precio:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim());
```

He intentado truncar o cambiar a double pero no he podido solventar

Agradeciera muchos si me ayudaran o me guiaran para solucionar este error

Comment: Prueba con Convert.ToDecimal(i.nombre.Split(new string[] {"Precio:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); y me avisas como te fue.

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funciono perfectamente de verdad muchísimas gracias

Comment: Vale lo pongo como respuesta entonces.

Comment: Correcto amigo coloquela como respuesta

Comment: Listo solo falta que lo marques como respuesta o la pregunta seguirá como abierta.

Comment: @JorgeLuisAlcantara una pregunta se puede colocar el separador de miles en esa misma linea de codigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se necesita para que acepte el valor correcto de los decimales, es que el servidor entienda cual es el formato correcto, esto se puede conseguir con la librería **using System.Globalization;**. Cuando el valor del string se convierte a decimal se aplica la sobrecarga con **CultureInfo.InvariantCulture**

```
Convert.ToDecimal(i.nombre.Split(new string[] {"Precio:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim(),
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```